# setState function (functional components) don't update state in console

Tags: reactjs

I have a functional component, and lets say the variables are:

```
const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(false);
```

I have a checkbox like this:

```
<label for='checking'><input type="checkbox" id="checking" checked={currentValue ? true : false} onChange={e => handleChecking(e)} />
```

And then I have a function:

```
const handleChecking = (e) => {
    setCurrentValue(e.target.checked);
    console.log(currentValue);
}
```

Now the problem is, even though the checkbox behaves as expected, the console.log shows me incorrect values.

When the checkbox is true, it shows me false.
When the checkbox is false, it shows me true.

It seems like the state is not being updated currently in the function, yet works as expected on the checkbox itself.

To make it more blunt, the output of this:

```
    console.log(e.target.checked);
    setCurrentValue(e.target.checked);
    console.log(currentValue);
```

is:

When the checkbox is true:

```
true
false
```

and when it is false:

```
false
true
```

Comment: why your checked property not be `checked={currentValue}`

Comment: I just simplified this example, and yes, we can for this example have `checked={currentValue}` but I still face that issue.

Answer (score 0):

`useState` hook is asynchronous, and will not immediately reflect the updated value.

You can use `useEffect` to access the changed value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(currentValue);
}, [currentValue])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I even tried a setTimeout, but that doesn't fetch the correct value either.

Comment: You can also check the state by putting thisconsole.log(currentValue); just before the jsx return statement of your component, also set timeOut does not gurantee that

Comment: And what do I do if I want to do some other thing based on the changedValue? Would I call that function from inside `useEffect()`;

So I setCurrentValue() in the `handleChecked()`, and then I want to perform some additional tasks.

Should I move all those tasks inside `useEffect()`?